# I want to use a transparent image as a button using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to use a transparent image as a button in a tkinter program.
I searched a lot, and I finally came to this:

```
def play():
    Gun = PhotoImage(file='Gun.png')
    GunButton = Button(win, image = Gun) #no command yet
    GunButton.photo = Gun
    GunButton.place(x=100,y=100)
```

It shows the button as well but the image is not transparent, it has gray background.
I tried this too but nothing changed:

```
def play():
    Gun = PhotoImage(file='Gun.png')
    GunButton = Button(win)
    GunButton.config(image=Gun)
    GunButton.photo = Gun
    GunButton.place(x=100,y=100)
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857757/transparent-backgrounds-on-buttons-in-tkinter), but the image is blank
I'm new to python I would be thankful if someone could help me

Comment: What are you expecting to be visible through the transparent parts of your images?  Tkinter widgets are *always* opaque rectangles - so your only actual option is the background color of the Button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.