# How can I achieve this type result using Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make transparent GUI using Tkinter in python, Please help me how can I make this type GUI
[Transparent GUI](https://carlfx.files.wordpress.com/2019/03/screen-shot-2019-03-11-at-1.25.19-am.png)
[image]

```
import tkinter as tk 
r = tk.Tk() 
r.title('Counting Seconds') 
button = tk.Button(r, text='Stop', width=25, command=r.destroy) 
button.pack() 
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent background in a Tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window)

Comment: What OS are you on? And is that an image on your screen or you just want the shape of the window like that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wm_attributes:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
# load image
root.image = tk.PhotoImage(file='image.gif')
# disable window movement
root.overrideredirect(True)
# setup start window position
root.geometry("+800+200")
# initialise wm attributes
root.wm_attributes()
# setup transparency
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
# setup label
label = tk.Label(root, image=root.image, bg='white')
label.pack()
label.mainloop()
```