# How to create Transparent text widget in python and tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Transparent text widget in python and tkinter like glass notepad

Answer (score 3):

For windows, you can create a `Text` widget, specify the background colour, and then use `wm_attributes` to set that colour transparent.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root,bg="white")
text.insert(tk.END,"This is a test message")
text.pack()
text.configure(font=("Times New Roman", 12, "bold"))
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could u answer by one more question?

Comment: How to create a GUI designer in python and tkinter?

Comment: Is that windows only @HenryYik ?

Comment: @Shubham That question is too broad to answer. If you came across a specific part where you got stuck, you can post a question and people will help.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window/19094652#19094652), there is no cross platform way to ensure background transparency, although I have not tested the above on MacOS or Linux.