# How to create a translucent window in tinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

I am trying to create a translucent window in Tkinter like the one in windows 11 [image]

How to do this? If we cannot do this can we capture a part of a screen and blur it using cv2 and use it as a continuously updating background?

Comment: I think this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window

Comment: The link gives answer to make it transparent, I want to make it like in windows 11 (translucent glass).Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @Sanjay The best that `tkinter` can offer without a lot of coding is using `root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)` to make the window slightly transparent (not translucent)

Comment: Hey I just added code below to do it with `tkinter`, this can be useful when you are making splash screens, do take a look :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not directly possible with `tkinter`. But:

If you use `PIL`, you can get the location of the window, and then take a screenshot, then blur it and then make it your app background. But this wont work if user tries to move/resize the application. But here is a rough code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, ImageGrab, ImageFilter # pip install Pillow

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1) # Hide the titlebar etc..

bg = Canvas(root)
bg.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
root.update()

# Get required size and then add pixels to remove title bar and window shadow
left   = root.winfo_rootx()
top    = root.winfo_rooty()
right  = left + root.winfo_width()
bottom = top  + root.winfo_height()

root.withdraw() # Hide the window
img = ImageGrab.grab((left,top,right,bottom)) # Get the bg image
root.deiconify() # Show the window

img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=5)) # Blur it 
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
bg.create_image(0,0, image=img, anchor='nw') # Show in canvas

label = Label(root,text='This is a translucent looking app')
bg.create_window(bg.winfo_width()/2,bg.winfo_height()/2,window=label) # Position in the center

root.mainloop()
```

Output with `tkinter`:

[image]

---

`tkinter` is not the best choice if you are trying to go for a modern look, use `PyQt` and check [qtacrylic](https://github.com/negated-py/qtacrylic)

Output with `PyQt`:

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `pygetwindow` why not use `root.winfo_rootx()`, `root.winfo_rooty()`, `root.winfo_width()`, and `root.winfo_height()`?

Comment: @TheLizzard My original solution actually involved using `winfo_geometry()` and getting dimension from there, but also I  tried different stuff out including `winfo_height()`, at the end I just copy pasted the code, but it would be better, I will edit it

Comment: You can use BlurWindow from pypi for using native windows blur too

Answer (score 1):

For live blur (native Windows blur) use ["BlurWindow"](https://pypi.org/project/BlurWindow/):

[image: FluentTkinter]

> python -m pip install BlurWindow

```
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll

from BlurWindow.blurWindow import blur

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='green')

root.wm_attributes("-transparent", 'green')
root.geometry('500x400')

root.update()

hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
blur(hWnd)



def color(hex):
    hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    blur(hWnd,hexColor=hex)
    

e = Entry(width=9)
e.insert(0,'#12121240')

e.pack()
b = Button(text='Apply',command=lambda:[color(e.get())])
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```