# How to display an image in Tkinter with a transparent background on MacOS (Ventura)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

According to the StackOverflow thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296157/7817891
The following code should display an image with a transparent background:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
# Hide the root window drag bar and close button
root.overrideredirect(True)
# Make the root window always on top
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
# Turn off the window shadow
root.wm_attributes("-transparent", True)
# Set the root window background color to a transparent color
root.config(bg='systemTransparent')

root.geometry("+300+300")

# Store the PhotoImage to prevent early garbage collection
root.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="photoshop-icon.gif")
# Display the image on a label
label = tk.Label(root, image=root.image)
# Set the label background color to a transparent color
label.config(bg='systemTransparent')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However, the code ends up making the entire Tkinter window invisible.

I have tried a couple of different approaches, but cannot find anything online that seems to work with recent versions of MacOS. Is there a way to still do this?